# Complication with jQuery.animate() when used in conjuction with location.hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, slider

I wrote a little sliding-script based on jQuery. To remember, which slide is currently active and to restore this slide on a reload, the `location.hash` is updated. In Chrome, this works just fine. In Opera and Firefox, the animation shows some odd behaviour. Though the CSS property is updated to the correct value, the sliding finishes between two slides. This behaviour is only present, when the `location.hash` property is updated.

Are there known complications when combining these two mechanisms? I cannot really imagine how they affect each other.

The relevant JavaScript code:

```
var currentPage = 0;
var lock = false;
var transitionTime = 500;

function changePage( direction ) {
    if( lock )
        return;

    var currIndex = currentPage;
    var nextIndex = currentPage + direction;

    var cPage = $( '#page' + currIndex );
    var nPage = $( '#page' + nextIndex );

    if( cPage.length == 0 || nPage.length == 0 )
        return;

    // Set lock
    lock = true;

    // Animate scrolling container
    var newPosition = -800 * nextIndex;
    $( '#scroller' ).animate( {
        left: newPosition
    }, transitionTime, function() {
        // Remove lock
        lock = false;
    } );

    currentPage = nextIndex;
    location.hash = 'page' + nextIndex;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sXGX3/show/)  Remove `/show/` from address bar to access jsFiddle edit page. Navigation is done via the arrow keys.

Comment: Regarding the analytics code: This is a free hoster and I cannot influence this. But the script seems to behave exactly as without the analytics code. The thing about the arrow I just forgot. Sorry about that

Comment: Hash values go from `#page0` to `#page6` while the slides themselves go from `Slide 1` to `Slide 6` (in Opera).

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, jsFiddle updated with missing slide number.

Comment: Here was my attempt for an answer with this [**Revised jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UeUvk/show) that works in Firefox except for the jump-to-page hash on page load feature, and just fails in Chrome. Please check out the CSS notes that might be useful. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing, it seems that the wrapper `div` is being moved to the left a little as the scroller `div` is moved left. Change the position of the wrapper `div` to `fixed` and it will resolve your issue.

```
div#wrapper {
    height: 220px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -375px;
    margin-top: -150px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    width: 680px;
}
```

Happy Coding! Here is the example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/y56x7/2/show/).